# How to scroll in the Terminal app "top"?

Tags: command-line

I've read the info page, but I can't find any way to scroll the list in `top`.

Maybe there is no way to scroll?... but there must, at least, be some way to filter the list, and I can't find that either.

How do I display line-entries which are off the page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have only one suggestion: use `htop` instead.

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Comment: Maybe it's called `top` for that very reason.. it may be by design that it only shows the **top** entries... (just guessing, but if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it probably is a duck ;)  ... It is very cabable at sorting by columns and add/remove collumns via a single key

Comment: There are some filters possible in `top` BTW, like filtering on user, process ID, &c., but `htop` has so many more possibilities, plus a UI that's easy to change from inside the program...

Answer (score 4):

The point of the *"TOP"* program is to tell you which processes are using the most resources or are at the TOP of the list.

For a full process list use *"ps"*:

```
ps aux
```

You can filter it with *"grep"*:

```
ps aux | grep firefox
```

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the up and down arrow keys will scroll through `top` on newer versions, specifically at least on the version of `top` that comes with Ubuntu 16.04.2 (`procps-ng` version 3.3.10).

But if the arrow keys don't work to scroll for you, it could just be an issue with your terminal emulator.

Take a look at the `top` man page:

> Lastly,  some  of  top's screens or functions require the use of cursor motion keys like the standard arrow keys plus the Home, End, PgUp and PgDn keys.  If your terminal or emulator does not provide those keys, the following combinations  are accepted as alternatives:
>
> ```
>           key      equivalent-key-combinations
>           Up       alt + \      or  alt + k
>           Down     alt + /      or  alt + j
>           Left     alt + <      or  alt + h
>           Right    alt + >      or  alt + l (lower case L)
>           PgUp     alt + Up     or  alt + ctrl + k
>           PgDn     alt + Down   or  alt + ctrl + j
>           Home     alt + Left   or  alt + ctrl + h
>           End      alt + Right  or  alt + ctrl + l
> ```

So if the up and down arrow keys don't work for you (make sure you hold them down, as [deto said](https://askubuntu.com/a/789964/453741)), try pressing `alt + \`, `alt + /`, `alt + k` and `alt + j`.

---

Note that this section of the man page does not exist on my RHEL 6.6 machine, which has `procps-ng` version 3.2.8 (you can see the version number with `top -v`), and so that version of `top` does not appear have any scrolling capability.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I'm finding that I can scroll top just fine in version 3.3.9 (Default on Ubuntu 14.04)

If you hold the down arrow, it'll look like you aren't scrolling, but just keep holding.  For each repetition, I believe there is a marker that is moving down, row by row (not visible) and when it hits the bottom the window scrolls down.

Also the PageUp and PageDown keys work a bit faster.